# ECD file not produced from the "Train Random Trees Classifier" tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, classification

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1 and i am trying to use the **Train Random Trees Classifier** tool to create an **.ecd** file, before finally using the **Classify Raster** tool to extract certain areas in the raster. 
I am using 8 bit unsigned SideScanSonar images that have been smoothed and edge enhanced with laplacian 5x5.

In the geoprocessing window i get the message that the tool has been run successfully, and it states the lcation of the new file it allegedly created. However, i can not find the **.ecd** file neither in that specific folder or in any folder on my computer.

Why is it nowhere to be found?

I have tried several training features, of different extent and sized. cant get it to work.

An **.ecd** file IS created when using the ISO cluster Classifier tool.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your training file is in the same format (including attributes) as the output from the Training Sample Manager. I had the same problem of a non-existent .ecd file happen when using training data in a shapefile with different attributes (built outside the Training Sample Manager).

To modify outside training data into a Training Sample Manager outputted file, from within the Training Sample Manager load your existing training data. Then rename and merge training samples as needed so that there is one training sample per class. Then save the training samples and use this new version in Train Randoms Trees Classifier.

For more details on the Training Sample Manager see here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/the-training-sample-manager.htm